# unexpected token in build.gradle when running react-native run-android

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, react-native

I am trying to run the AwesomeProject in an android emulator using react-native out of the box which is pretty straightforward.

I followed all the steps for installing the android studio and emulator.

When trying to build the project using `react-native run-android`, I however get the following error:

```
/android/build.gradle': 18: unexpected token: ( @ line 18, column 9.
             ()
             ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I am pretty new to gradle and java in general. Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might need to post the code for the same file here.

Comment: Indeed you should  post your build.gradle, then we can take a look at the problem

Comment: Please post your /android/build.gradle file code. It is not decipherable with the limited information you have provided.